# I am writing a program for finding numbers in a string

Tags: python

This code will check a string and return numbers in sequence and will provide individual numbers as they appear in string. I know there are ways much better than my code to find numbers in strings, this is an assignment. I only have problem with the loop, the loop should run till the end of the string and terminate. I am unable to do that.

```
#variables
start = None
end = None
zero= None
one = None
two = None
three = None
four = None
five = None
six = None
seven = None
eight = None
nine = None
check = None
def numfind():
    #will find numbers in a string and allocate position in the string
    global zero
    global one
    global two
    global three
    global four
    global five
    global six
    global seven
    global eight
    global nine
    global end
    global start
    zero=text.find('0',end)
    one=text.find('1',end)
    two=text.find('2',end)
    three=text.find('3',end)
    four=text.find('4',end)
    five=text.find('5',end)
    six=text.find('6',end)
    seven=text.find('7',end)
    eight=text.find('8',end)
    nine=text.find('9',end)
def numstart():
    #will find the smallest number from among the previous function output and will allocate it as the start of the number, in "start" variable, will use slicing function to return the number
    global zero
    global one
    global two
    global three
    global four
    global five
    global six
    global seven
    global eight
    global nine
    global start
    for n in [zero,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine]:
        if start is None:
            if n != -1:
                start = n
                #print start
            else:
                continue
        else:
            if n != -1:
                if start>n:
                    start=n
                    #print start
            else:
                continue
def numend1():
    #Will find the space after numbers begin, will use "end" in the slicing function to return the first number from the string.
    global start
    global end
    end=text.find(" ",start)
    #print end
def endchecker():
    #this is some bullshit I came up with to terminate the loop, but doesn't work :(
    global zero
    global one
    global two
    global three
    global four
    global five
    global six
    global seven
    global eight
    global nine
    global start
    global end
    global check
    for n in [zero,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine]:
        if check is None:
            if n != -1:
                check = n
                #print check
            else:
                check=n
        else:
            if n != -1:
                check=n
                    #print check
            else:
                if check>n:
                    continue
                else:
                    check = n
text=raw_input("Please enter a string containing a set of numbers:") 
while True:
    numfind()
    endchecker()
    print check
    if check == -1:
        break
    numstart()
    numend1()
    try:
        if end!=-1:
            number1=float(text[start:end])
            print number1
        else:
            number1=float(text[start:])
            print number1
            break
    except:
        print "Error"
        break
    print "End of Program"
```

Comment: what is going on with all the globals in your code?

Comment: don't use globals, use return values; use lists.

Comment: You make use of `globals` a lot in your code...that's not advised

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your code, but a little confused at what you are going to do, it seems that you are trying to get the number substrings from a text.

```
#python
text=raw_input("Please enter a string containing a set of numbers:")

s = ""
for c in text:
    if c >= '0' and c <= '9':
        s += c
    else:
        if len(s) != 0:
            print s
            s = ""
if len(s) != 0:
    print s

print "End of Program"
```

Hope that will help you some.

some advices, it's better debuging while coding, don't write a big block of code but never tried to run it, a small but useful code is much better.

BTW, it is much better to avoid using Global, which will make your code hard to read, function parameters and return values is better.

Answer (score 0):

Man, what is going on in you code? I am not exactly sure what you're trying to do with your code. If all you need to do is to check a string whether it contains numbers and display those numbers in sequence, then you can do them very easily using regular expressions.

```
#python
import re
string = raw_input("Enter a string: ")

match = re.findall(r'\d', string)

# print the found numbers in the same sequence
# as found in the string
for i in match:
    print i,
```

If you want to print the numbers in ordered sequence, you may use the sorted() function. Modify the for loop as follows.

```
for i in sorted(match):
    print i,
```

If you are looking for longer substrings, you can modify the pattern as follows:

```
match = re.findall(r'\d+', string)
```

Or the non-greedy version:

```
match = re.findall(r'\d+?', string)
```

Again, I am not exactly sure whether this solves your problem.